# show that the set of orthogonal matrices is bounded

Tags: vector-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, orthonormal

I'm trying to demonstrate that the set of orthonormal matrices $\mathcal{O}(n,m) =\{ A : A^TA = I_m\} $ is bounded but sort of lost

Comment: With what norm?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the columns must form an orthonormal basis, so no entry can have absolute value greater than 1.

Comment: @a_confused_student ??? You did write orthonormal matrices, which you shouldn't have -they're _orthogonal_ matrices. The columns of a orthogonal matrix form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich i'm just confused student pls help.

Comment: the notation and terminology here is a bit troubling.  OP has  
$\mathcal{O}(n,m) =\{ A : A^TA = I_m\}$
presumably for real matrices.  (The set of complex matrices obeying this is unbounded.) *Very commonly* $\mathcal{O}(n,m)$ denotes signature, e.g.  $\mathcal{O}(n-1,1)$ denotes (a generalization of) the Lorenz group.  OP is evidently using this to refer to $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ such that $A^TA = I_m$.  This is not an 'orthonormal' matrix and is only an orthogonal matrix if $n=m$.

Comment: @a_confused_student Help with what? You've been _given_ an answer to your question...